# EXCEPTION: No provider for $scope! (function (scope, elementRef) { -> $scope)

Tags: angular, angular2-upgrade

I am using ngUpgrade to use an angular1 directive in my angular2 app. I followed the steps mentioned on angular2 [upgrade guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html)

See this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/qQMTa3IpUsREZvpaNmBH) for code.
It is resulting me into this error -

```
EXCEPTION: No provider for $scope! (function (scope, elementRef) { -> $scope)
```

Any clue what I may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding -

```
angular
  .module('interestApp')
  .directive('appRoot',upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component(AppComponent));
```

because (quoting from [the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html)) -

> The root of the application is always an Angular 1 template.

That's why Angular 1 needs to know about the Angular 2 AppComponent.

I found that removing the following line from the `main.ts` helps clear the `No provider for $scope!` error -

`platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);`

Because you don't need two bootstrap processes in an hybrid app.

Comment: If you don't bootstrap using `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);` then how does your app get bootstrapped?

Comment: The upgradeAdapter does it